# svg animate does not work without indefinate

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, svg-animate

I am trying to add animation onto `rect` svg in React, using `animate`. The current code works with the `repeatCount="indefinate"`, but I only want to animate when the `rect` is first rendered. Is there a way to do that?

I have tried removing repeatCount, but that does not work.
Thanks

```
     <rect
        width={20}
        height={40}
        x={props.xScale(dataWithOffset.whiskers[0])}
        y={0}
        fill={'blue}
        opacity={0.4}
      >
        <animate
          attributeName="opacity"
          from="0"
          to="1"
          dur="2s"
          begin="0s"
          fill="freeze"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
      </rect>
```

Comment: and add on repeatCount : infinite? or you like other result...